# just last digits in string by regex

Tags: regex

I have difficulty with regex. My goal is to retrieve the last and only last numbers in the string if exists.

- temp-15 - return 15
- temp14t - return nothing
- temp12temp13 - return 13
- 1412315235temp?1 - return 1
- temp-14t# - return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will do it:
`(\d+)$`

1. \d matches digits
2. expects one or more digits
3. $ End of string